# robocopy powershell just get a list of folder and file names

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to use robocopy in powershell to get first a list of all folders in the fileshare and secondly the list of files that are in the particular folder only.
when I use `robocopy \\grape\Documents\testACASmigration2 NULL /L /S /NJH /BYTES /FP /NC /XJ /R:0 /W:0`
it outputs this

```
     0  \\grape\Documents\testACASmigration2\
           0    \\grape\Documents\testACASmigration2\test\
           0    \\grape\Documents\testACASmigration2\test\migration\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         3         3         0         0         0         0
   Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : 05 August 2015 10:25:11
```

Is there anyway I can get in 2 arrays, one for all the folders and one for all the files in the particular folder
I AM NOT WANTING GET_CHILDREN OR ANYTHING LIKE THAT AS IT DOESN'T WORK FOR PATHS ABOVE 260. ROBOCOPY DOES THAT IS WHY I HAVE ASKED THE QUESTION WITH ROBOCOPY

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
$folder=[IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("C:\temp")
$files=[IO.Directory]::GetFiles("C:\temp")
```

That gives me the following output:

[image]

Comment: No, I am using robocopy as that deals with paths over 260chars the `[\IO.Directory]` will not

Comment: what about:
    $dirs = robocopy "C:\temp" "C:\temp_2" /l /s /nfl /xx /nc /ns /njh /njs 

to get the directorys at least

Answer (score 0):

using the powershell get-childitem command with the -Recurse switch gets you exactly that.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse


    Directory: C:\Users\Jower\OneDrive\Documents\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                       
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                       
d-----       05-08-2015     12:15                sub1                                                                       
-a----       05-08-2015     12:15              6 test1.txt                                                                  
-a----       05-08-2015     12:15              6 test2.txt                                                                  
-a----       05-08-2015     12:15              6 test3.txt                                                                  


    Directory: C:\Users\Jower\OneDrive\Documents\test\sub1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                       
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                       
-a----       05-08-2015     12:15              6 test4.txt
```

Although you might use something like this to actually put it inside two arrays.

```
$array1 = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Directory # only return the directories
foreach ($folder in $array1)
{
    $array2 = get-childitem $folder -file #get the files in this folder
    # Process $array2
}
```